# EasyAdmin3: Passing additional variables to twig-template (EDIT page)

Tags: symfony, twig, parameter-passing, crud, easyadmin

### Background

I want to display entity-independent information in the EDIT-page. According to the official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/crud.html#passing-additional-variables-to-crud-templates) it can be solved with `configureResponseParameters`-function.

### Problem

So I implemented that function into my CRUD-controller.

- on INDEX twig template: I can use/find the variable
- on EDIT twig template: I cannot use/find the variable

Any idea why?

How can I achieve to pass data to my EDIT-twig template? Many Thanks!

### My Files

**PersonCrudController.php**

```php
class PersonCrudController extends AbstractCrudController {
    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud {

        $crud->setFormThemes([
            'mystuff/person_edit_form.html.twig', '@EasyAdmin/crud/form_theme.html.twig'
        ]);

        return $crud;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
        // ...
        yield TextField::new('specialDisplay')->setFormTypeOption('mapped', false);
        // ...
    }

    public function configureResponseParameters(KeyValueStore $responseParameters): KeyValueStore
    {
        $responseParameters->set('testtesttest', '123xyz');
        return $responseParameters;
    }
    // ...
}
```

**mystuff/person_edit_form.html.twig**

```
{% block _Person_specialDisplay_row %}
    {{ testtesttest }} {# throws: Variable "testtesttest" does not exist. #}
    {{ dump() }}       {# cannot find "testtesttest" anywhere in dump #}

    {# ... here comes the rest that is working perfectly ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi!, Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue since my idea was to pass some variable from the CRUD controller to the `edit` template so I could access to it from my custom form template that overrides a field from the edit view, which it may have sense but there is the gotcha:

`configureResponseParameters` provides the variables that the action template will receive, in this case it was the `crud/edit` template, meaning that the variables that returns `configureResponseParameters` are setted in the *twig context of the whole action template* which is totally different from the *twig context of the single form field* we want to pass the variable to. So that's the reason why when doing the dump in the custom block the setted variable does not appear; the block that we are customizing will not receive the setted variables, and therefore cannot access to them from the form.

For what I've read in the [docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#passing-additional-variables-to-crud-templates) I understand that `configureResponseParameters` is intended to be used when overriding the whole templates, and it has sense because if you want to pass some variables to the CRUD action template is because you are intending to customize multiple things. So if you want to access to the variables setted in `configureResponseParameters` you will need to override the action template (`crud/edit`, in this case) and access to it from there:

```
{# original template from EasyAdminBundle #}
{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/crud/edit.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

  {# your setted vars are going to appear here #}
  {{ dump()  }} 
  {# the original template contents are rendered with parent() #}
  {{ parent() }}
    
    {# imagePreviewSrc was my setted var so you can access to it in this way, for example #}
    <img id="preview" {% if imagePreviewSrc %} src="{{imagePreviewSrc}}" {% endif %} alt="Preview">  

  {{block('rest_of_blocks_you_want_to_include')}}
  {% include 'or_any_other_file.html.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```

As you mentioned that the data it's independent from the entity that you are editing, it is not necessary to declare a field to render the data that you want because fields are for the entity properties, so this solution may work well for you.

-- *What happened in my case?*

I realised that what I wanted was to render one property that actually belonged to my entity, so by setting a field with its linked property I ended up retrieving the variable that I wanted to pass to the template by accessing to the twig context from the form theme that I was customizing; remember that we are in the `edit` view that corresponds to an *entity*, so if you are in the situation that you want to include some variable to customize your forms probably the entity already has this value, so pass it to some field and you would do some customization like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming).